# Setting production build react application variables after build

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Using create-react-app after running `npm run build` is there a way to pass in props to the application? If I wanted to set the background of the built application to a passed-in color is that possible?

```
<div id="root" (color)="'blue'"></div>
<script src="myApp.js"></script
```

Comment: Was my answer useful, or do you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a config file `cfg.js` in the **public** folder of your app containing variables like so:

```js
var DIV_COLOR = "#00FFFF";
```

Then you need to include that file in your `index.html`:

```html
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/cfg.js">
</script>
```

Now you can access those variables in your app like so:

```html
<div backgroundColor={window.DIV_COLOR}></div>
```